# How to perform custom paging

Tags: asp.net

Hy All,

I want to provide Numeric and First/Next/Prev/Last Button pager and DropDown for page size in grid view.

So please give me any link or any example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with the drop down you mentioned:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/08/14/GridView-DropDownList-Pager.aspx

With the GridView, paging is pretty much out of the box :)

Comment: i want to add button dynamically for e.g.: First Prev 1 2 3 4 5 Next Last now when user click on next then First Prev 6 7 8 9 10 Next Last so i have to add button dynmically and attach event with them...

Comment: Override the event handler for the page changed event - and check the page number; then add the drop down dynamically like you mentioned. I wouldn't recommend dusing this approach - too messy. Go with the example in the link provided :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add PagerSettings to your gridview
eg.
PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" Position="TopAndBottom" Visible="true", also please read this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagersettings.aspx

Comment: i want to add button dynamically for e.g.: First Prev 1 2 3 4 5 Next Last now when user click on next then First Prev 6 7 8 9 10 Next Last so i have to add button dynmically and attach event with them.

Comment: i think i have to create one class which inherit grid view class and override grid method and use this custom control....